# Fancybox Conflict issue

Tags: popup, fancybox

I have quick view pop up which uses jquery.fancybox.pack.js and a slider with image gallery popup which uses a jquery.fancybox.js

There is a script error in console as "TypeError: $.fancybox.getInstance is not a function" and also there is an issue with slider image gallery poopup(opening first image only on every image click)

I tried to solve the script error by removing jquery.fancybox.js file initialized in local.xml file. Now the script error is solved. But my slider with image gallery popup will not work.

When I initialized both jquery file in local.xml, got an error as "Error: fancyBox already initialized".

What could be the reason for this. How can I solve the issue with slider image gallery pop up.

Are these files(jquery.fancybox.pack.js and jquery.fancybox.js) same?

Please help.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem when I was trying to integrate Fancybox V3 with Wordpress. I have Visual composer enabled maybe it is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are mixing different versions of fancyBox.

`jquery.fancybox.pack.js` is packed version of `jquery.fancybox.js` and it was shipped with v1 and v2.

V3 now has minified version (`jquery.fancybox.min.js`) and only v3 contains `getInstance` method.

Comment: Is it not possible to use jquery.fancybox.pack.js and jquery.fancybox.js on same page?I removed both these files and added jquery.fancybox.min.js file. But both popup are not working.What do I need to do to solve the issue.